# Hide HOST resources from a docker container

Tags: linux, docker, cgroups, resources, container

I have a linux server with 100GB of RAM & 56Cores, I run a docker container with limit in Memory and CPU and I use `cgroups` too (I limited Memory & CPU to 50GB & 20Cores).

With all that when I use `top` or `htop` in docker container I can see all of server resources!. I know that with all I did I only limit usage of RAM and CPU, but is there any way to hide server resources from docker containers?